# Pulling to refresh only works when pulling is happening around FlatList component

Tags: react-native

I'v used `FlatList` component and need to implement `refreshControl` prop on it. This the code:

```js
<FlatList
    refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
    }
    data={allTuitions}
    renderItem={({item}) => renderItem(item)}
    ListEmptyComponent={listEmptyComponent}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={itemSeparatorComponent}
/>
```

It works correctly. But the problem is: The area the `FlatList` component covers, pulling is correct. Otherwise, I can't pull. How can I extend the area I can refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place your FlatList inside a View with your desired height. For example, if it should fill all available height, you can try `flex: 1` to make a start. This way, your FlatList will grow to the available size.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList ...options />
</View>
```